# Counting chars, words and lines in a file

Tags: c, file, character, line

I try to count the number of characters, words, lines in a file.
The txt file is:

```
The snail moves like a
Hovercraft, held up by a
Rubber cushion of itself,
Sharing its secret
```

And here is the code,

```
void count_elements(FILE* fileptr, char* filename, struct fileProps* properties) // counts chars, words and lines 
{
    fileptr = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
    int chars = 0, words = 0, lines = 0; 
    char ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fileptr)) != EOF  )
    {
        if(ch != ' ') chars++;
        if (ch == '\n') // check lines 
            lines++;
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0') // check words
            words++;
      
    
    }
    fclose(fileptr); 
    properties->char_count = chars;
    properties->line_count = lines; 
    properties->word_count = words;

}
```

But when i print the num of chars, words and lines, outputs are 81, 18, 5 respectively
What am i missing?
(read mode does not changes anything, i tried "r" as well)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You have several thinking errors in this, e.g. 2 spaces after one another would count multiple words. Also windows might make newlines with \r\n

Comment: It looks like there is one extra newline charcter in the input file.

Comment: Also note that the return value of `fgetc()` should be stored to `int` variable, not `char`. Otherwise, it will be difficult to distinguish one of valid characters and EOF.

Comment: also what do you want to do exaclty? do you want only a-zA-Z counted as char? Or with spaces and special chars? Or only prinable ones?

Comment: @Nidhoegger yeah, trying to count only alphabetical letters as a char

Comment: @MikeCAT ok, i missed that,i changed to int.

Comment: How can i check if there is an extra newline character in file?

Comment: if there is an extra newline, there is also an extra line. so thats fine.

Comment: One way is viewing the file via binary editor or `od -Ax -t x1`

Comment: @MikeCAT if there is an extra new line, a texteditor will show an extra line, which should be counted as such... There is no need to check for double newlines...

Comment: regarding: `fileptr = fopen(filename, "rb"); `  1) when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful..  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror()` with your error message.  It will output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  2) your opening a text file, so do not use "rb", just use "r"

Comment: regarding: `if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')`  a text file will not contain a `\0'

Comment: regarding: `if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')`  this will over count the words when there is  a double space, etc.  Suggest implementing a two(2) state machine where the states are 'in a word' and 'not in a word'

Comment: suggest including the header file: `ctypes.h` so you can use macros like: `isdigit()`, `isspace()`, isprint(), etc

Comment: regarding: `void count_elements(FILE* fileptr, char* filename, struct fileProps* properties)`  why passing the parameter: `fileptr`?   the file is opened and closed within the bounds of the function so no other function can use that variable

Comment: @user3629249 thx for ctypes.h tip. It makes much easier. I did not understand your question regarding "fileptr" btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I whipped up gives me the same results as the gedit document statistics:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count_elements(char* filename)
{
    // This can be a local variable as its not used externally. You do not have to put it into the functions signature.
    FILE *fileptr = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
    int chars = 0, words = 0, lines = 0; 
    int read;
    unsigned char last_char = ' '; // Save the last char to see if really a new word was there or multiple spaces
    while ((read = fgetc(fileptr)) != EOF) // Read is an int as fgetc returns an int, which is a unsigned char that got casted to int by the function (see manpage for fgetc)
    {
        unsigned char ch = (char)read; // This cast is safe, as it was already checked for EOF, so its an unsigned char.

        if (ch >= 33 && ch <= 126) // only do printable chars without spaces
        {
            ++chars;
        }
        else if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0' || ch == ' ')
        {
            // Only if the last character was printable we count it as new word
            if (last_char >= 33 && last_char <= 126)
            {
                ++words;
            }
            if (ch == '\n')
            {
                ++lines;
            }
        }
        last_char = ch;     
    }
    fclose(fileptr); 
    
    printf("Chars: %d\n", chars);
    printf("Lines: %d\n", lines);
    printf("Words: %d\n", words);

}

int main()
{
    count_elements("test");
}
```

Please see the comments in the code for remarks and explanations. The code also would filter out any other special control sequences, like windows CRLF and account only the LF

Comment: shouldn't we also increment the lines if(ch ==  '\0')  ?

Comment: not neccessarly. maybe lines need to be initialized with 1 if at least one char is found. but your textdocument might have multiple `\0` in it which is neither illegal nor a line break.

Comment: If I test this with a file containing `öäü` (UTF8 encoded) it'll return `Chars: 0 Lines: 1 Words: 0`

Comment: Jupp, but this code can be extended to include those from the extended ascii charset

Answer (score 2):

Your function takes both a `FILE*` and `filename` as arguments and one of them should be removed. I've removed `filename` so that the function can be used with any `FILE*`, like `stdin`.

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { /* type defining the struct for easier usage */
    uintmax_t char_count;
    uintmax_t word_count;
    uintmax_t line_count;
} fileProps;

/* a helper function to print the content of a fileProps */
FILE* fileProps_print(FILE *fp, const fileProps *p) {
    fprintf(fp,
            "chars %ju\n"
            "words %ju\n"
            "lines %ju\n",
            p->char_count, p->word_count, p->line_count);
    return fp;
}

void count_elements(FILE *fileptr, fileProps *properties) {
    if(!fileptr) return;

    properties->char_count = 0;
    properties->line_count = 0;
    properties->word_count = 0;

    char ch;
    while((ch = fgetc(fileptr)) != EOF) {
        ++properties->char_count; /* count all characters */

        /* use isspace() to check for whitespace characters */
        if(isspace((unsigned char)ch)) {
            ++properties->word_count;      
            if(ch == '\n') ++properties->line_count;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    fileProps p;

    FILE *fp = fopen("the_file.txt", "r");
    if(fp) {
        count_elements(fp, &p);
        fclose(fp);

        fileProps_print(stdout, &p);
    }
}
```

Output for the file you showed in the question:

```
chars 93
words 17
lines 4
```

**Edit:** I just noticed your comment "*trying to count only alphabetical letters as a `char`*". For that you can use `isalpha` and replace the `while` loop with:

```c
    while((ch = fgetc(fileptr)) != EOF) {
        if(isalpha((unsigned char)ch)) ++properties->char_count;
        else if(isspace((unsigned char)ch)) {
            ++properties->word_count;
            if(ch == '\n') ++properties->line_count;
        }
    }
```

Output with the modified version:

```
chars 74
words 17
lines 4
```

---

A version capable of reading "wide" characters (multibyte):

```c
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>

typedef struct {
    uintmax_t char_count;
    uintmax_t word_count;
    uintmax_t line_count;
} fileProps;

FILE* fileProps_print(FILE *fp, const fileProps *p) {
    fprintf(fp,
            "chars %ju\n"
            "words %ju\n"
            "lines %ju\n",
            p->char_count, p->word_count, p->line_count);
    return fp;
}

void count_elements(FILE *fileptr, fileProps *properties) {
    if(!fileptr) return;

    properties->char_count = 0;
    properties->line_count = 0;
    properties->word_count = 0;

    wint_t ch;
    while((ch = fgetwc(fileptr)) != WEOF) {
        if(iswalpha(ch)) ++properties->char_count;
        else if(iswspace(ch)) {
            ++properties->word_count;
            if(ch == '\n') ++properties->line_count;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE.UTF-8");      // set your locale
    FILE *fp = fopen("the_file.txt", "r");
    if(fp) {
        fileProps p;
        count_elements(fp, &p);
        fclose(fp);
        fileProps_print(stdout, &p);
    }
}
```

If `the_file.txt` contains one line with `öäü` it'll report

```
chars 3
words 1
lines 1
```

and for your original file, it'd report the same as above.

Comment: isalpha wont account for special characters as öäü for example.

Comment: @Nidhoegger If those are representable by a single unsigned char in the current locale `isalpha` should return `true`. One may have to use wide mode to support multibyte encodings though.

Comment: @Nidhoegger I added a version supporting multibytes. I put `öäü` in a file (UTF8 encoded). The file itself is then 7 bytes.